# Group array rows on date, sort, and print grouped data with special headings

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, datetime, grouping

I have array like this:

```
$events = [

[
  'title' => 'Event 1',
  'description' => 'Some Text',
  'date_added' => 2016-05-06 14:57:39
],

[
  'title' => 'Event 2',
  'description' => 'Some Text',
  'date_added' => 2016-05-08 14:57:39
],
[
  'title' => 'Event 3',
  'description' => 'Some Text',
  'date_added' => 2016-05-09 14:57:39
],
[
  'title' => 'Event 4',
  'description' => 'Some Text',
  'date_added' => 2016-05-09 15:57:39
]

];
```

I need to show data like this:

```
**Today events:**
Event 4,
Event 3

**Yesterday events**
Event 2

**May 6th events**
Event 1
```

How can I do this? Is it possible?

Comment: Loop through the array and use the date as key and add the values as array to the key

Comment: Have you tried something? Show us some code please.

Comment: This question is rather broad. Is the problem the sorting? The grouping? or the conversion of dates to "today" and "yesterday".

Comment: The second one - I want to show all events from today in today list, yesterday events in yesterday list and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works exactly as you want. Try this:

First, we need to sort the records date wise. We can use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function for this.

```
function compare_date($a, $b) {

    if ($a['date_added'] === $b['date_added']){
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a['date_added'] > $b['date_added']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($events, "compare_date");
```

Next, we're creating a custom array that holds titles date wise.

```
foreach($events as $event) {

    $today_date =   strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    $event_date =   strtotime($event['date_added']);
    $diff       =   floor(($today_date - $event_date)/(60*60*24));

    switch($diff) {
        case 0:
            $title             = "Today events:<br/>";
            $result[$title][]  = $event['title'];
            break;
        case 1:
            $title             =  "Yesterday events:<br/>";
            $result[$title][]  =  $event['title'];
            break;
        default:
            $title             = date("M jS", $event_date)." Events:<br/>";
            $result[$title][]  = $event['title'];
    }
}
```

Finally, we are traversing through this $result and showing the desired output.

```
foreach($result as $k => $rslt) {

    echo $k;
    echo implode("<br>", $rslt);
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using usort():

```
function date_compare($a, $b) {
    $t1 = strtotime($a['date_added']);
    $t2 = strtotime($b['date_added']);
    return $t1 - $t2;
}    
usort($events, 'date_compare');
```

To display them, you can use the following foreach statement:

```
foreach ($events as $key) {
    $dt = new DateTime($key['date_added']);
    $date =  $dt->format('F j');
    if($current != $date) {
        $current = $date;
        echo "<br>**".$date." events:**<br>";
    }
    echo $key["title"]."<br>";
}
```

The output:

```
**May 1 events:**
Event 3

**May 3 events:**
Event 1

**May 8 events:**
Event 2

**May 9 events:**
Event 4
```

Hope this solution works. Wish you the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this :

```
// method to compare two values
function compare_date($a, $b) {

    if ($a['date_added'] === $b['date_added']){
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a['date_added'] > $b['date_added']) ? -1 : 1;
}

// callback function
usort($events, "compare_date");

$today = date("Y-m-d");
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("yesterday"));

$myEvents = array();

foreach ($events as $key => $val) : 
    $datetime = new DateTime($val['date_added']);
    $record_date = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');

    if ($today == $record_date):
        $myEvents['today'][] = $events[$key];
    elseif ($yesterday == $record_date):
        $myEvents['yesterday'][] = $events[$key];
    else :
        $myEvents[$record_date][] = $events[$key];
    endif;  
endforeach;

// display event
foreach($myEvents as $i => $v):
    if ($i!="today" && $i!="yesterday"):
        echo date('M d', strtotime($i)) . "<br>";       
    else :
        echo $i . "<br>";
    endif;

    foreach ($v as $e):
        echo $e['title'] . "<br>";
    endforeach;
    echo "<br>";
endforeach;
```

Out put of above code is :

**today**

Event 4

Event 3

**yesterday**

Event 2

**May 06**

Event 1